# How do I store data from getSymbols (quantmod library) to a list?

Tags: r, list, quantmod

Here's the code I'm running

```
library(quantmod)
library(tseries)
Stocks={}
companies=c("IOC.BO","BPCL.BO","ONGC.BO","HINDPETRO.BO","GAIL.BO")
for(i in companies){
   Stocks[i]=getSymbols(i)
}
```

I'm trying to get a list of dataframes that are obtained from `getSymbols` to get stored in `Stocks`.
The problem is that `getSymbols` directly saves the dataframes to the global environment `Stocks` only saves the characters in `companies` in the list.

How do I save the dataframes in the Global Environment to a list?

Any help is appreciated.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is `lapply`

```
library(quantmod)
Stocks <- lapply(companies, getSymbols, auto.assign = FALSE)
Stocks <- setNames(Stocks, companies)
```

from `?getSymbols`

> auto.assign : should results be loaded to env If FALSE, return results instead. As of 0.4-0, this is the same as setting env=NULL. Defaults to TRUE

---

Using a `for` loop you could do

```
companies <- c("IOC.BO", "BPCL.BO", "ONGC.BO", "HINDPETRO.BO", "GAIL.BO")
Stocks <- vector("list", length(companies))

for(i in seq_along(companies)){
  Stocks[[i]] <- getSymbols(name, auto.assign = FALSE)
}
Stocks
```

Comment: Quick question though, what exactly is this line doing?
`Stocks <- vector("list", length(companies))`
what is `"list"` supposed to mean here?

Comment: @NikhilGopal This creates an empty list of length 5 (the length of companies). `Stocks` allocates the space for the output. This more efficiency than growing a vector. `vector()` has two arguments: the type of the vector (“logical”, “integer”, “double”, “character”, etc) and the length of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

In my version of quantmod (0.4.0) it was necessary to set `env=NULL` in the functions' parameters, then the entire data frame is returned

Answer (score 0):

Use the following argument as  getSymbols(i, auto.assign=FALSE)

Comment: I did this but now I only get one value in each index of `Stocks`, it doesn't save the entire dataframe to index 1 :/