# extract names from df in r

Tags: r

I have a question regarding extracting strings.
i have a string with financial tickers. For extending these tickers I want to auto maize the getSymbols function

So for example I have the df

```
ticker = c("BTC-USD", "^GDAXI")
```

with the function I want to use it in getSymbols by doing

```
getSymbols = (Extracted_String, source = "yahoo")
```

the end product should be then 2 dfs with one for BTC-USD and the other for the DAX

thank you!

Comment: You say you have a data frame, but `ticker = c("BTC-USD", "^GDAXI")` is a vector. You could do `data_list = lapply(ticker, getSymbols, source = "yahoo")`

Comment: Related: [How do I store data from getSymbols (quantmod library) to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791718/how-do-i-store-data-from-getsymbols-quantmod-library-to-a-list)

Comment: i do have all ticker names in the string ticker
and I want to extract the first ticker, f.ex. "BTC-USD" to put it in getSymbols
then I want to extract the second ticker, "^GDAXI and put it in getSymbols

Comment: I guess `getSymbols` `Symbols` is already vectorized - `a character vector specifying the names of each symbol to be loaded`

Comment: Stocks = lapply(ticker, getSymbols, source = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE)